# Linux echo cpu (core) name/number for a given shell in PBS

Tags: linux, cpu, cpu-usage, tbb, pbs

I have a simple C++ code that uses Intel's TBB to run a list of scripts on a cluster using PBS.  I want to confirm that I am using all the cores as intended.  Each node has 16 cores.  I have created the scripts to take varying amounts of time such that if the list is divided evenly I will have idle cores.  If the list is divided out as cores become available I should have no idle cores.  The code appears to work fine on a single node but not for multiple nodes.

I want something similar to `echo $HOSTNAME` except for the core.  Google failed me and produced results for echoing the number of cores or how much the cores are used.  I have tried using top and monitoring the job run but this doesn't tell me which core.

Comment: Can you add a pseudo-code please? I'm not sure I understand what is your problem. Do you use `parallel_for(0, N, [](int i){ run_script(i); }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is up to the Linux scheduler to decide which process gets which core at any given moment. It makes those decisions many times a second frequently moving processes from core to core depending on the load.

You can get a snapshot of the process to cpu allocation with the `psr` option of the ps command:

```
ps -o pid,psr,cmd -28832
  PID PSR CMD
28832   1 bash
```

I.e. here `bash (pid=28832)` is assigned to the second core that has `processor id=1`.

From `C` code you could use the `getcpu(2)` call defined in `linux/getcpu.h`.

To assign a process to a specific set of cores you could run `numactl(8)` or `taskset(1)` specifying a cpu affinity mask.

Comment: I ended up going with the sched_getcpu that I found through the getcpu method.  Thanks for the solution.